# How do I learn about Physics, more than just a high school level?

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I want to learn a bunch of things about physics, from cosmic expansion to the leading GUTs. I, however, don't necessarily want to be a physicist, and don't want to know the math if I don't need to. I just want to know how and why things work in our universe, without knowing mathematically why, as a hobby. How could I do this? Preferably for free. I've watched series like Cosmos (the NdGT version), but I want to delve deeper and wider.

Comment: start with books. for particle physics, especially experimental, try "The Hunting Of The Quark" by Riordan. for early-universe cosmology, try "The First Three Minutes" by Weinberg. Also look up the Scientific American anthology books (collected articles from the magazine), a number of them are available and they are excellent.

Comment: The Feynman Lectures on Physics.

Comment: I don't think you could learn more than the basics in physics if you avoid maths in it. Maths is the language of physics and helps to put the concepts of physics forward on the paper. The basic intuition of physics alone doesn't prove a physical phenomenon. Any physical phenomenon is accepted only when a "mathematical proof" satisfies the phenomenon. Hence you must not avoid maths but try to be habitual with it.

Answer (score 6):

To put it bluntly: you're fooling yourself if you think that you can have real understanding without the math.

My recommendation for a next step would be *The Theoretical Minimum* (I have in mind [the book by Susskind and Hrabovsky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465075681), but they have other formats) because it feeds you only an operational view of the math only when you need it.

That won't give you what you want, but it will give you a taste of how physics is developed and give you a hint about why the math is indispensable.

---

My other favorite book to recommend to truly interested laymen is Feynman's *QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter*, because it also doesn't flinch from giving you the real theory and explaining what math has to be done (but it doesn't equip you to do the math for yourself).

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want to learn more about the universe and how it works my advice would be to embrace it's language. It isn't too entertaining learning all the basics and such but it really does get fun.

A good book recommendation to get your juices flowing
*The Elegant Universe* [by Brian Greene](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/039333810X)

The book goes into special and general relativity as well as some basics of quantum mechanics. Then at the end there is a bit of String theory (Brian is a string theorist).